# differential equation $a(x).y'+b(x).y=\phi(x)$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

Let $(E)$ : $a(x).y'+b(x).y=\phi(x)$ \
such as $a$ and $b$ are two continuous functions, verifies $a(x),b(x)≠0 : x\in \mathbb{R}^+$

Let $S$ be the solution set of $E$.
Is $S$ a VECTOR SPACE ?

My answer :
If $\phi(x)=0$, then $S$ will be a vector space.
but what if $\phi(x)≠0$, or in this case we can just say that $S$ is infinite ?

Comment: Let $y(x)$ be a solution. Is $\alpha y(x)$, for constant $\alpha$, a solution too?

Comment: Obviously, it's not a solutions so $S$ can't be a vector space, so can we say that S is infinite ?